# List of Ushio to Tora anime (2015) 2S skipped manga chapters?

Tags: ushio-to-tora

I managed to find the [list for the first season](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/2000121-anime-and-manga-other-titles/73053729#msg_2) but I haven't found anything regarding the second. Does somebody here know?